# Can't able to set the value for useState hook in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, console, response

I used axios to access the 'http://localhost:8000/api/lists/', after accessing it, if I use console.log() , then the values are printing in console, but while setting the state it shows an empty array.. how to set the values of res.data to setArrData(). can anyone help to solve it ?...

```
const [arrData, setArrData] = React.useState([])
useEffect(()=>
        getData()
},[])

const getData=()=>{
    let inp=field.inp

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/lists/',{
            'input':inp
        },
        {
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        }
    ).then(res=>{
        if(res.status===200){
            setArrData(res.data)
            console.log(arrData)
            console.log(res.data)
        }
    }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `setState` in `asynchronous`, so you can't see new state after `setState`. If you want to see the change of the `arrData`, you can use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(arrData);
}, [arrData])
```

Comment: but printing again and again, it seems like an infinite loop, how to solve it?

Comment: You call setArrData in useEffect?

Comment: No I wasn't, if I set the state using setArrData(JSON.stringify(res.data)) the loop wasn't appears, but instead if I set the state using setArrData(res.data)then the infinite loop gets executed...

Comment: Please ask another question with detail code

Comment: Error Solved, I used an Fetch method  to access an API instead of Axios, Now it works fine.. anyway I will post the another question ASAP regarding the infinite loop which happens while using Axios.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Setters in any react hooks are asynchronous. React under the hood sets the state and fires the events to re-render the component or any change that depends on this state, all of it but asynchronously.

`setArrData` sets the data but to read the updated data, you should use `useEffect` hook for above-mentioned reason.

```
useEffect(()=>
    console.log(arrData); <-- on first render the value here will be what you have assigned while defining the state i.e. [] in this case.
}, [arrData]) <--- this is dependency array, 
                   that tell this *useEffect* to run when *arrData* state changes
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your Information, It helps me a lot and also working fine..